# Divisibility of a number by $(4k+3)$ in minimum time

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Please suggest any algorithm with minimum time complexity to check whether a number $n$ is divisible by at least one $(4k+3)$ where $k>0$ is integer and $(4k+3)\le n$?

Comment: Define "divisible"? does it mean that $number$ MOD $(4k+3) = 0$?

Comment: yes divisible means MOD ==0

Comment: please again read the question i forgot something to mention now i have written!

Comment: is the algorithm should be in pseudo-code? some kind of a programming language? what may you use?

Comment: anything will work!

Comment: so...just loop through numbers between 1 and n, and in each iteration check whether n MOD (4k+3) == 0, if it does, return "true". If the loop is over and it didn't find a divisor, return "false".

Comment: that is trivial i want this is minimum time complexity!

Comment: isn't O(n) short enough? what is the complexity required?

Comment: given nummber is very large something 10^18. Is it not possible to do this in <O(n) ?

Comment: Nothing that I can see. Good luck :)

Comment: @Macavity That won't help; 7 and 21 are different modulo 4 and both are divisible by 7 ($k = 1$).

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes, missed that..

Comment: There is probably no better method than complete factorization. To quote Terry Tao http://mathoverflow.net/a/10062/297 " the moment one has a way of extracting even one non-trivial useful bit of information about the factors of a number, it is likely that one can vary this procedure ... and soon extract out enough bits of information to pin down the factors completely".

Answer (score 2):

Here are some heuristics that may help, depending how much the persoin who gave you your $n$ hates you:

We may assume that $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ as we may simply divide off any factor of $2$ and know that there exists a factor $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
Also, it may be advisable to perform trial division with small primes (both primes  $\equiv 1\pmod 4$ to make $n$ smaller and primes $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ to check if we are lucky).

Next, perform a primality check on $n$ - if it is prime there is no such divisor. I suggest the Miller-Rabin test because it has a nice positive side effect for the problem at hand, so that I reformulate the test her:

1. Determine integer $r$ and odd $d$ such that $n-1=2^rd$ (note that by assumption $r\ge 2$)
2. Pick a random integer $a$ between $1$ and $n$
3. Compute $b_0=a^d\bmod n$ and for $s=1,\ldots,r-1$ let $b_s=b_{s-1}^2\bmod n$

Now note that

- If $b_0\not\equiv 1\pmod n$ and all $b_r\not\equiv -1\pmod n$, this proves that $n$ is composite (Miller-Rabin).
- If $b_r\equiv -1\pmod n$ for some $r>0$, this shows that $-1$ is a square modulo $n$ and hence $n$ has no factor $\equiv 3\pmod 4$

In other words, if a round of MR fails to prove compositeness ($n$ either prime or pseudoprime) it may at the same time prove that there is no factor $\equiv 3\pmod 4$; showing pseudo-primality will usually suffice.
Unfortunately, this will still not help us if MR proves $n$ composite or if we repeatedly obtain $b_0\equiv \pm1$.

---

Putting the above heuristics aside, I am afraid that we cannot beat complete factorization. That is, if one produces products of two large primes (as during RSA key generation) and obtains a reuslt $\equiv 1\pmod 4$ (as one does in 50% of the cases), there is no known method to distinguish between products of two primes $\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and products of two primes $\equiv -1\pmod 4$. or at least so I think I recall reading somewhere.